# WiX installer - Set ApplicationFolder from ComboBox

Tags: wix

I'm writing a WiX installer for a group of medical device SW products that must install in specific directories off the root of C:.  IE no "ProgramFolders" for these.

They run in dedicated environments and have been verified and validated using these directories.

I have a custom welcome dialog that has a combobox:

```
    <Control Id="TypeCombo" Type="ComboBox" X="178" Y="162" Width="120" Height="20" Property="InstallChoiceResult" ComboList="yes" Sorted="no">
      <ComboBox Property="InstallChoiceResult">
        <ListItem Text="Base dev 1" Value="1"/>
        <ListItem Text="Base dev 2" Value="2"/>
        <ListItem Text="Base dev 3" Value="3"/>
        <ListItem Text="Base Simulator" Value="4"/>
      </ComboBox>
    </Control>
```

The choice by the FSE sets the property "InstallChoiceResult".   After they hit next I need to set my application folder based on their choice.  IE  if they chose "Base dev 1" then I need to set APPLICATIONFOLDER to C:\BASEDEV1.  If they choose Base dev 2 then we go to C:\BASEDEV2

Being new to WiX I'm strugging with the sequence.  It seems from examining my MSI with Orca that the InstallUISequence comes AFTER the costing occurs.  When I try to set the APPLICATION folder using a group of custom actions it complains that since it is a directory it must be set before CostFinalize.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but if my UI seems to be running AFTER that how can I set the directory I need?  My custom actions currently look like:

```
<CustomAction Id="SetDev1" Property="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Value="C:\BaseDev1" Execute="immediate" />
<CustomAction Id="SetDev2" Property="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Value="C:\BaseDev2" Execute="immediate" />
<CustomAction Id="SetDev3" Property="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Value="C:\BaseDev3" Execute="immediate" />
<CustomAction Id="SetDevS" Property="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Value="C:\BaseDevS" Execute="immediate" />

<InstallUISequence>
  <Custom Action="SetDev1" Before="InstallDlg2">InstallChoiceResult=1</Custom>
  <Custom Action="SetDev2" Before="InstallDlg2">InstallChoiceResult=2</Custom>
  <Custom Action="SetDev3" Before="InstallDlg2">InstallChoiceResult=3</Custom>
  <Custom Action="SetDevS" Before="InstallDlg2">InstallChoiceResult=4</Custom>
</InstallUISequence>
```

The general jest of what I need to do is basically this:

Display dialog (FSE chooses 1, 2, 3 or simulator)
After next is pressed, Set ApplicationFolder based on property from ComboBox
Install into the set ApplicationFolder

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the directory values to APPLICATIONFOLDER using **SetDirectory** element. No need to use Custom action and bind the directory values directly to the List item. Make the Combo box property is public (All letter in uppercase).

```
<Control Id="TypeCombo" Type="ComboBox" X="142" Y="158" Width="120" Height="16" Property="INSTALLCHOICERESULT" ComboList="yes" Sorted="no">
    <ComboBox Property="INSTALLCHOICERESULT">
        <ListItem Text="Base dev 1" Value="C:\BaseDev1" />
        <ListItem Text="Base dev 2" Value="C:\BaseDev2" />
        <ListItem Text="Base dev 3" Value="C:\BaseDev3" />
        <ListItem Text="Base Simulator" Value="C:\BaseDevS" />
     </ComboBox>
</Control>

<SetDirectory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Value="[INSTALLCHOICERESULT]" Sequence="execute" />
```